# Collecting water before pesach

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, bitul-batel-null, issur-vheter

People who are worried about chometz in water on pesach collect water before pesach so it can be Me'vutal before pesach.
However won't they cause themselves a bigger problem?
If they are worried for crumbs (they clearly don't hold of the famous mashehu has a shiur psak), now that the water is still for 24 hours (see aruch hashulchan 467 that we don't have an issue of kvisha if the water is moving) they have to be worried with kvisha even if they sift it out before drinking?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: [related](/q/6630/170)

Comment: I don't see anything about _kavush_ when the water is moving in AHS 467. I see in _s'if_ 47 about _kavush_, but nothing about moving water. Am I simply missing it? In any event, this post would be greatly improved if it would include more translations of the Hebrew where possible. Not everyone using this site has the same level of Hebrew.

Comment: I don't understand why you suspect kevisha makes this worse. It's batel before pesach. That's the whole point.

Comment: Im referring to the aruch hashulchan 33. If you come to a different conclusion in that aruch hashulchan please let me know.

Comment: Double aa we see in the shulchan aruch that even with bitul before pesach if there is some mamoshes (residue) and its recooked on pesach everyone holds that its chozer vneyor there wont be bitul.